# How to simplify my create element code?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create 2 elemets, 1 with id and 1 without.
I have the following code and want to know how to simplify it. Any helps? Thanks a lot.

```
 var element = $('<div/>').attr({'id': tool}).addClass('s-Tool')             
                .append(
                  $('<div/>').css({'padding': '0.5em 1em'}).html(text)
               );

//only different is attr id

 var elementClass = $('<div/>').addClass('s-Tool')             
                .append(
                  $('<div/>').css({'padding': '0.5em 1em'}).html(text) 
               );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elementClass = $('<div />', {'class': 's-Tool'})
                   .append($('<div/>').css('padding', '0.5em 1em').html(text)),
    element = elementClass.clone(true).attr('id', tool);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the actual HTML:

```
var element = $('<div id="tool" class="s-Tool"><div style="padding: 0.5em 1em;">' + text + '</div></div>')
```

To do this with a different id, you can make it a function:

```
function makeMyElement(id, text) {
    var element = $('<div id="' + id + '" class="s-Tool"><div style="padding: 0.5em 1em;">' + text + '</div></div>')
    return(element);
}
```

Comment: `.html()` actually protects from some "unwanted" things: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/nNpUz/

Comment: @zerkms - When you control the inputs, there is nothing that needs to be protected from.  So, it depends upon the origin of the `text` variable and whether `.html()` is advantageous or just an unneeded function call.